# Can one migrate from Fedora (28) to CentoOS 8 Stream using new repos and DNF?

Tags: fedora, centos8, fedora-server

I've got a server running Fedora 28 that is primarily an RDBS host running PostgreSQL 10.7-1:

```
[Fedora 28]$ dnf list postgresql-server
Last metadata expiration check: 0:20:19 ago on Mon 12 Jul 2021 09:39:03 AM MDT.
Installed Packages
postgresql-server.x86_64                                                                                    10.7-1.fc28                                                                                    @updates
```

For reasons, we'd like to migrate that machine to CentOS 8 Stream, which, nicely, happens to be currently supporting 10.17.1:

```
[CentOS 8 Stream]$ dnf list postgresql-server
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:08 ago on Mon 12 Jul 2021 09:58:15 AM MDT.
Available Packages
postgresql-server.x86_64                                                                       10.17-1.module_el8.5.0+827+770862af                                                                        appstream
```

It seems to me that I may be able to replace the Fedora 28 repos with CentOS 8 Stream repos and do dnf upgrades, followed by a reboot.

Is this a huge risk? I'd like to preserve the Postgres data layout and simply fire it up again (perhaps with a few tweaks) rather than have to do a clean install from ISO.

Comment: This has never been supported, and if it breaks, you get to keep both pieces.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't try this on a production server. Take a snapshot or spin up a clone, then give it a try.

Comment: I would love to hear your results!

Comment: Well, I'm not really interested in making it an experiment, I'll just install CentOS 8 Stream from an ISO the old-fashioned way. The Postgres data is on a standalone disk, so that makes it easier to get it running post-install.